# Player and "laser" disappears when objects collide

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a game where I have a player that is suppost to shoot enemies falling down the screen. The issue is that the enemy objects dissapears before having collided and the player also dissapears before the collission happens. Instead the objects disapears when it's on the same tredjectory as the enemy object which is not what is intended.

```js
var left_key = 37;
var up_key = 38;
var right_key = 39;
var down_key = 40;
var space_key = 32;
var player_movment = 4;

var lastLoopRun = 0;

var controller = new Object();
var enemies = new Array();

function createSprite(element, x, y, w, h) {
  var result = new Object();
  result.element = element;
  result.x = x;
  result.y = y;
  result.w = w;
  result.h = h;
  return result;
}

function toggleKey(keyCode, isPressed) {
  if (keyCode == left_key) {
    controller.left = isPressed;
  }
  if (keyCode == right_key) {
    controller.right = isPressed;
  }
  if (keyCode == up_key) {
    controller.up = isPressed;
  }
  if (keyCode == down_key) {
    controller.down = isPressed;
  }
  if (keyCode == space_key) {
    controller.space = isPressed;
  }
}

function intersects(a, b) {
  return a.x < b.x + b.w && a.x + a.w > b.x && b.y + b.h && a.y + a.h > b.y;
}

function ensureBounds(sprite, ignoreY) {
  if (sprite.x < 20) {
    sprite.x = 20;
  }
  if (!ignoreY && sprite.y < 20) {
    sprite.y = 20;
  }
  if (sprite.x + sprite.w > 480) {
    sprite.x = 480 - sprite.w;
  }
  if (!ignoreY && sprite.y + sprite.h > 480) {
    sprite.y = 480 - sprite.h;
  }
}

function setPosition(sprite) {
  var e = document.getElementById(sprite.element);
  e.style.left = sprite.x + "px";
  e.style.top = sprite.y + "px";
}

function handleControls() {
  if (controller.up) {
    player.y -= player_movment;
  }
  if (controller.down) {
    player.y += player_movment;
  }
  if (controller.left) {
    player.x -= player_movment;
  }
  if (controller.right) {
    player.x += player_movment;
  }
  if (controller.space && laser.y <= -120) {
    laser.x = player.x + 9;
    laser.y = player.y - laser.h;
  }
  ensureBounds(player);
}

function showSprites() {
  setPosition(player);
  setPosition(laser);
  for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
    setPosition(enemies[i]);
  }
}

function checkCollisions() {
  for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
    if (intersects(laser, enemies[i])) {
      var element = document.getElementById(enemies[i].element);
      element.style.visibility = "hidden";
      element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
      enemies.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
      laser.y = -laser.h;
    } else if (intersects(player, enemies[i])) {
      var element = document.getElementById(player.element);
      element.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else if (enemies[i].y + enemies[i].h >= 500) {
      var element = document.getElementById(enemies[i].element);
      element.style.visibility = "hidden";
      element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
      enemies.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
}

function updatePositions() {
  for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
    enemies[i].y += 4;
    enemies[i].x += getRandom(7) - 3;
    ensureBounds(enemies[i], true);
  }
  laser.y -= 12;
}

function addEnemy() {
  if (getRandom(50) == 0) {
    var elementName = "enemy" + getRandom(10000000);
    var enemy = createSprite(elementName, getRandom(450), -40, 45, 45);

    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.id = enemy.element;
    element.className = "enemy";
    document.children[0].appendChild(element);

    enemies[enemies.length] = enemy;
  }
}

function getRandom(maxSize) {
  return parseInt(Math.random() * maxSize);
}

function loop() {
  if (new Date().getTime() - lastLoopRun > 50) {
    updatePositions();
    handleControls();
    showSprites();
    checkCollisions();

    addEnemy();

    lastLoopRun = new Date().getTime();
  }
  setTimeout("loop();", 2); //6:10 episode 2 <-- forklaring:
}

document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
  toggleKey(evt.keyCode, true);
};

document.onkeyup = function(evt) {
  toggleKey(evt.keyCode, false);
};

var player = createSprite("player", 250, 460, 20, 20)
var laser = createSprite("laser", 0, -120, 2, 50);

loop();
```

```css
#player {
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

#background {
  background: black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

#laser {
  background: green;
  width: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

.enemy {
  background: blue;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="background"></div>
<div id="player">
  <img src="xwing.png" height="20px" width="20px">
</div>
<div id="laser"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for your collision detection isn't correct.
Try this:

```
function intersects(a, b) {
  return a.x > b.x - a.w && a.x < b.x + b.w && a.y > b.y - a.h && a.y < b.y + b.h;
}
```